# trying to hide a div and its content with angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to hide a div and its content using angularjs. I have created a scope variable initialized to false and paased to the div to hide it. the div is not yet hidden and its contents
 this is the javascript snippet

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function MyCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.myvalue = false;

}    
    </script>
```

I am calling the above javascript div to hide it >>>>

```
<div ng-app class="container" style="padding: 10px;">
                <!-- end of shopping cart -->
                <div ng-controller="MyCtrl" id="products" class="row mas">
                <div class="col-sm-3 filter">
                    <div class="col-item">


                        <div class="info">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="price col-md-6">
```

the div and its content is not hiding on loading the page. kindly assist

Comment: gosh where is my wrong

Comment: read the angular doc or find some angular snippet to see how to construct angular app first... and use ng-if and ng-hide to hide the div you want

Comment: I tried ng-hide=true but it did not work

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fc2gcmvL/  just an example.... if it doesn't work, that means you have problems including angularJS.

Comment: Your `MyCtrl` function isn't bound to any angular module as a controller, it's just a global function, how would angular know how to inject $scope into it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular has directives for DOM visibility.

`<div ng-hide="true"></div>`

or

`<div ng-show="false"></div>`

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

`ng-hide` and `ng-show` *do* render the DOM node—albeit hidden via css class helpers. `ng-if` does not render the DOM node until the expression is truthy.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf